# Is it good to keep DB constraints in hibernate entities

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

while i was refactoring a codebase i came through hibernate annotations like

```
@Column(name = "personal_email", nullable = true, length = 64)
private String personalEmail;
```

in **USER** entity ... actually there is  **data-truncation** error if **personalEmail** is more than 64 characters.

I personally feel that keeping annotations like this is a bad practice.i think we do not have to spoil our code by Database entity meta info.

my approach is I will remove length and nullable annotation names and let DB notify in case of any constraint violation.

I think only advantage of keeping this type of annotation is It will not propagate erroneous data to DB level.

I want to know your suggestion...

anyways i will alter column width for personalEmail in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which system you trust more. Hibernate (Java) or your DB.

Maybe this list will help you.

**Advantages for Hibernate**

- is to keep track about your constraints in the same codebase. There will be no switching around between both systems to check them.
- Feel free to provide more detailed information for the user and your own logfile.

**Disdvantages for Hibernate**

- Each constraint modification HAS TO be compiled. There is no runtime change possible and thus more maintenance (Server restart, ... etc.).

**Advantages for database**

- You can change from JavaEE / JavaSE to any other system.
- Make constraint changes while runtime if necessary (be careful not recommended).

**Disadvantages for database**

- Not in the same codebase. Violations might be hard to find out.
- More code in Java to translate more specific user information. Database logs aren't user friendly.

Comment: Actually, it depends whether you'll be creating your database schema through hibernate or not. If not, then there's no advantage (except maybe for informational purposes) in having the annotations.

Comment: I was thinking about changing constraints while runtime shoudn't be done. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/alter-table-on-live-production-databases

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you're saying.

Comment: I actually thought constraint changes during runtime are possible. But this shouldn't be done. Because there might be some reasons which could lead to critical behavior especially in production systems. There is detailed explanation behind the stackexchange link.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/alter-table-on-live-production-databases

Colleageus warned me about 7 years ago to change MS SQL constraints without maintenance steps (especially database backup).

Comment: I have no idea how that's related to my comment. It's definitely risky to alter a database in production, but it's still *possible*. In any case the database is the "master" when it comes to constraints, and the JPA annotations are mainly useful if you intend to have Hibernate generate the schema instead of doing it yourself.